# MacBook showing battery service required no longer turns on after sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I got a MacBook Pro 2016 at the office. It was working great however the battery kept saying it needed to be serviced and wasn't really good at holding charge either. 100% would reach ~60% in 30 mins. But I didn’t mind as I am mostly plugged in anyway.

Then I brought it home, used it and didn’t shut it down but rather clicked the power button (which I presume is standby), closed the lid and put it on the shelf.

In the morning I try to turn it on and nothing! It's not turning on. I kept it charging for hours but still no response. Tried the SMC reset but nothing. I am suspecting it's because of the battery but what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You know that, at the very least, the battery needs replacing. There could also be a problem with the power unit. However, hardware problems are best diagnosed in the presence of the machine itself. Take it to an Apple Store, or other Apple-authorised technician.

*(Unless, when you say you 'got it at the office', it's the property and responsibility of your employer: in which case you should return it to them.)*

A technician will be able to confirm what needs doing, and how much it will cost, leaving you to decide whether that's worthwhile. *If you got it very cheap from office surplus, then a few hundred dollars (or equivalent) would be worth it, IMO.*

Comment: Yeah the office showed it to their designated technician and it turns out an IC on the board had fried!. Now I m scratching my head because there is no way in hell it got exposed to any sort of liquid. I had it, I used it, put in nicely in the shelf, got at out and it wasn't working. How the IC got burnt I have no idea.